# Your own " Timer.Interval"

Tags: c#

I have a question about c#, but I have no idea how to google it or something. So I''m going to ask it here:

In c#, you have things like "Timer.Interval". Is it possible to make something similair like that myself?

For example, I have this void called "writeLine". I have this boolean, UseDelay, so that my function waits a while before writing things down. I want that boolean to become accessible as "writeLine.UseDelay = false" or "if (writeLine.UseDelay == false)" etc. I'm just curious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about is actually a `Property` of a class. There are ofcourse ways you can implement your own properties (actually just public variables inside the structure of your class) and your own methods (for example, take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042(v=vs.100).aspx)). If you're interested in further constructions and options, there is plenty of information on the web.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know it was called a property. Now I can research further! Thanks!